# ng-click on parent clicks through children

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a `<div>` element which has another `<div>` element as its child.

I added the `ng-click` directive to the parent, and expected it not to be fired when clicking the child. However, it does.

```
<div class="outer" ng-click="toggle()">
    <div class="inner">You can click through me</div>
</div>
```

Why is it doing this, and how can I avoid it?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10177/) demonstrating the issue

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You have to cancel event propagation, so the click event of the parent element won't get called. Try:

```
<div class="outer" ng-click="toggle()">
    <div class="inner" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">You can click through me</div>
</div>
```

When you click the child element, its event gets triggered. But it doesn't stop there. First the click event of the child element is triggered, then the click event of the parent element gets triggered and so on. That's called event propagation, To stop event propagation (triggering of the parents click events), you have to use the above function, `stopPropagation`.

---

## [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/pxh85mg8/)

I added some CSS padding, so the example is clearer. Without padding the child element takes up the whole inner space and you can not click on the parent without clicking on the child.

Comment: how can `.outer` div is clickable if there's nothing text directly insde that.

Comment: And e.stopPropagation() should be used in parent div not in child div so that child div can't be assigned click event....

Comment: True, I'll adjust my answer and add a working example

Comment: Actually, I just tested it and my above example seems to work fine. If you use stopPropagation() on the parent element instead of the child, it does not have the desired effect. It kind of makes sense, if you want to prevent the parents event to be triggered, you have to stop it before it gets called.

Comment: Well, I made the mistake of not looking at OPs original jsFiddle. If anyone wants to see the fixed version of OPs jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ghzsg40/1/

Comment: `ng-click="$event.stopPropagation(); clickFunctionForInnerDiv();"` to make some different from a parent action and not to call `toggle()` after

Comment: (click)= "$event.stopPropagation()" works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set different functions for the parent and the child, you can send $event as a parameter for the child function and stopPropagation inside of it. Like this:

```
<div class="outer" ng-click="onParentClick()">
    <div class="inner" ng-click="onChildClick($event)">You can click through me</div>
</div>
```

and in your controller:

```
function onChildClick(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    //do stuff here...
}
function onParentClick(){
    //do stuff here..
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me! I just changed a little by calling the `stopPropagation()` method inside the directive tag. 

`ng-click="onChildClick($event); $event.stopPropagation()"`

Comment: @FelipeRugai - thanks, this worked for me too....after I spelled `stopPropOgation` correctly.  :-P