# AngularJS - Selection of text triggers ng-click in parent in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, angularjs-ng-click, stoppropagation

I am experiencing a problem, to which I currently have no suitable solution:

Having an input field and when selecting the text and the mouse cursor is moved beyond the input field, the ng-click-event on the parent gets triggered when releasing the mouse button. It seems to make sense, since mouseup is triggered, but this is not the behaviour I want.

However, this only occurs in Chrome-Browser, in Firefox, I can't reproduce this issue.

Here's a simple plunker to demonstrate:

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/tNvKNdDRIE9CUqlk?preview

Just try to mark the text and move the mouse beyond the input-field.

- Expected Behaviour: Background stays Gray.
- Actual Behaviour:
     Background gets Green, showing that the ng-click in the background
     has happened.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Had the same issue before and here I found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28010244/ng-click-on-parent-clicks-through-children

Comment: Nope, this is in partial the same issue, the same behaviour I described is actually happening in the accepted answer: http://jsfiddle.net/pxh85mg8/

In the below, if you mark the text and hold + move your mouse out of the area to the white area (out of the border of red), then the alert still shows up when releasing your mouse.

Answer (score 0):

[A working Plnkr](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/lKXEh98mumo3tb6j?preview)

I'm saving the last "mousedown" element - and than decide whether to init Background color change ("$scope.active")